# HTML File Upload in ASP.NET: HttpPostedFile Attributes Are Empty

Tags: asp.net, html, file-upload

In my ASP.NET web form, I'm trying to customize my File Upload panel. What I do is simply put an HTML input button and a textbox. And there's a hidden HTML file upload control. When user clicks on the button, file select window appears, when user selects the file, the value is written to the visible textbox.

It's all good so far. But I'm having a problem while trying to attach the selected file to email in code page.

Here's the HTML markup:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="clickme" runat="server" ImageUrl="Images/browse.png" OnClientClick="$('#uploadme').click(); return false;" />
<input id="uploadme" name="uploadme" type="file" style="visibility: hidden;" onchange="CopyMe(this, 'txtFileName');" />
<input id="txtFileName" type="text" name="txtFileName" readonly="readonly" class="file-path" />
```

And the JS (I use this in order to copy the file name only and write it into txtFileName just to show to user):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function CopyMe(oFileInput, sTargetID) {
    var arrTemp = oFileInput.value.split('\\');
    document.getElementById(sTargetID).value = arrTemp[arrTemp.length - 1]; 
}
```

And the CSS:

```
input[type=file] { width: 1px; }
```

I'm using the below code in my .cs file to get the file attributes:

```
HttpPostedFile file = Request.Files["uploadme"]
```

But I kept on getting null value. So after some research, I've learnt that my form has to use `enctype="multipart/form-data"` property. Since my .aspx file is under a master page file, I added this property to the form in my master page file. Now `Request.Files["uploadme"]` is not null but its file name is empty string and its ContentLength is 0.

I'm unable to understand what might be the source to this issue. If it's because of using Master Page's form, I can't add a form to my child page because it says a page can have only 1 form. I don't know if I could use JavaScript for uploading because I need to email the file after uploading so I don't know how to get the file after I upload via JS.

How can I solve this problem? It could be one way or another, all I need is a stylized upload panel and to e-mail file after uploading.

Answer (score 0):

You're using a master page and I'm presuming that you are using .net 2.0 or greater. If that's the case, use a FileUpload control (you can still hide it using CSS). Using the FileUpload control means you won't need the enctype attribute (although you shouldn't generate any problems having it there).

This all being said, I don't believe to you copy values into file type fields and have documents upload. This would be a MAJOR security flaw as a website could potentially upload files from your machine without your knowledge.